# How to draw a circle using turtle in python?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I wanted ask how can I draw a circle using turtle module in python just using turtle.forward and turtle.left? I use the code below:

```
 for i in range(30):
     turtle.forward(i)
     turtle.left(i)  
 turtle.done()
```

What I get is that the line does not stop once I get the full cirle. How can I code so that I have a circle of specific radius and that I have a full stop once the circle is drawn (without using turtle.circle).

Comment: If you want to draw 30 sides and be back at your starting point facing the original direction, how many degrees do you have to turn each time?

Comment: Should this depend on the length of the side? Like the whole spin is 360 degrees and then depending on the length of the side I have to figure out the degree of a turn, is that your point?

Comment: Imagine that you turn without advancing and want to do a complete turn in 30 steps, how much would you turn on each step? It's always a good idea, when you don't understand a situation, to start with a simpler problem; here, try to do it in 4 steps. If you now move forward at each step, how much do you have to turn?

Comment: if in 4 steps then 360/4 = 90. But I dont understand how link this with the length of the side.

Comment: Try it in your room and walk the square. If you make a bigger square, does the angle change? Then you have your answer...

Comment: Thank you! I got your point. Just last question, Below I run the code, but how can I assign maximum number of sides to define the angle of a turn so that it is automatic (like in the example below it is 10)   for i in range(10):
    turtle.forward(10) 
    turtle.left(360/10) 
turtle.done()

Comment: Assign it to a variable: `steps = 10; for i in range(steps): turtle.forward(<whatever you want>); turtle.left(360/steps)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this image as a reference,
[image]

Essentially you need to draw the inscribed polygon with n sides.

The initial **left** turn will be ϴ/2.

Then **forward** by a = 2rsin(ϴ/2).

Each **forward** is followed by a **left** turn of the full ϴ, except that after the last **forward** we want only a **left** turn of ϴ/2 so that the heading will be correctly updated to be tangential to the circle (or arc).

Something like this,

```
import turtle
import math

def circle2(radius,extent=360,steps=360):
    if extent<360 and steps==360:
        steps=extent
    
    theta=extent/steps
    step_size=2*radius*math.sin(math.radians(theta/2))
    turtle.left(theta/2)
    turtle.forward(step_size)
    for i in range(1,steps):
        turtle.left(theta)
        turtle.forward(step_size)
    
    turtle.left(theta/2)
    

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed(0)
turtle.getscreen().tracer(False)

circle2(50)
circle2(100,180)
turtle.up()
turtle.home()
turtle.down()
circle2(130)
circle2(130,360,10)

turtle.update()
turtle.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to draw a circle the best thing to do is to simplyfy the problem, if we consider moving 1 space for each degree of the circle then we can simply write this as

```py
def draw_circle1():
    for _ in range(360):
        turtle.forward(1)
        turtle.left(1)
```

[image]

Now what do we know about this basic circle that we drew? well we know it took 360 steps and each step was 1. so the circle has a circumference of 360. we can use a bit of math to calculate the radius.

```
circumference = 2 * 3.14... * radius
360 = 2 * 3.14... * radius
360 / 2 / 3.14... = radius
radius = 57.29...
```

So now we can reverse this, if we want to specify a circle of a given radius, we can calculate what circumference that circle should have. divide that by the 360 degrees and we know what size step to take before each turn of 1 degree.

```py
def draw_circle(radis):
    circumfrence = 2 * math.pi * radis
    step_size = circumfrence / 360
    for _ in range(360):
        turtle.forward(step_size)
        turtle.left(1)
```

if we run this for 3 separate circles each increasing in size you see it gives us a consistent result

```py
draw_circle(20)
draw_circle(40)
draw_circle(60)
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.done()
```

[image]

So now we have a function which can accept a radius and draw a circle based on that radius

Answer (score 0):

A spirograph code

```
from turtle import Turtle
import random

josh = Turtle()
josh.color('DarkRed')

def random_color()->tuple:
    r = random.randint(0,255)
    g = random.randint(0,255)
    b = random.randint(0,255)
    return (r,g,b)

josh.speed('fastest')
josh.pensize(2)
for i in range(72):
    josh.circle(100)
    josh.right(5)
    colormode(255)
    josh.pencolor(random_color())
        
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(800,800)
screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: There are already several answers here with much more explanation. What does this answer do better than them? Please read [answer].

Answer (score -1):

Example here,

```py
import turtle

def circle(distance, sections):
    angle = 360/sections
    for i in range(1, sections+1):
        turtle.forward(distance)
        turtle.left(angle)

circle(20, 30)
turtle.done()
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a SPIROGRAPH using turtle. Final output:

[image: final output]

```
import random
import turtle

from turtle import Turtle, Screen

tim = Turtle()

tim.shape('arrow')

turtle.colormode(255)

def random_colour( ):
    r = random.randint(0, 255)
    g = random.randint(0, 255)
    b = random.randint(0, 255)
    return (r, g, b)

tim.speed('fastest')

def draw_spirograph(size_of_gap):
    for _ in range(int(360/size_of_gap)):
        tim.color(random_colour())
        tim.circle(100)
        tim.setheading(tim.heading()+size_of_gap)

draw_spirograph(5)

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```